# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5

I am trying to create a test class (JUnit 5) using Intellij Idea but I get the bellow error. When I created the test class it did NOT show the fix button so I am pretty sure the library is in class path.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.createListeners(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:45)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 13 more
```

My build.gradle looks as below:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

group 'ict221'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.11
mainClassName = 'boardgame.gui.RunGame'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
    version = "11.0.2"
}
```

Any help is much appreciate it.

Comment: Add `testRuntime("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.4.2")`?

Comment: thanks but where should I add this ?

Comment: Inside `dependencies {`.

Comment: added to build.gradle but still getting the same error...I am using java 12. might that be an issue?

Comment: See also http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentionned by @CrazyCode in comments, with Intellij you need to specify the version of JUnit (because Intellij is bundled with old version of JUnit)

Add this :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.6.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.6.1")
}
```

Comment: after updating spring-boot to 3.0.0, 
i have add this to fix the issue :  


testImplementation group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher', version: '1.9.1'

Comment: For maven just use specified in the answer dependency and `<scope>test</scope>`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding just the `junit-platform-launcher` worked for me

```xml
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
       <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.2</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
```

```
testImplementation group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher', version: '1.7.2'
```

Comment: The OP asked for a Gradle solution - this is maven.

Comment: Apologies. Added gradle for people who does not understand maven and how it can be converted to gradle.

Answer (score 1):

try entering these depencies for junit5 in a gradle project

```
testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.2")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2")
testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a `build.gradle` for a simple application with **JDK 17**, **Gradle 7.5.1** and **JUnit Jupiter 5.9.0**, which causes IntelliJ IDEA to correctly run unit tests with JUnit.

Notice that there is no need to add test dependencies as it is done automatically by configuring `testing` section.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

group = 'your.app'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}

testing {
    suites {
        test {
            useJUnitJupiter('5.9.0')
        }
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = 'your.app.App'
}
```

**src/main/test/your/app/AppTest.java**

```
package your.app;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class AppTest {

    @Test
    void testFeature() {
    }
}
```