# NoClassDefFoundError - Project with IntelliJ + Maven 3.8.4 + JUnit+ OpenJDK 11.05

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying  to run unit tests via JUnit Plugin in IntelliJ 2021.3.3, but everytime I try to run them, I got this error message on console:

```
Exception in thread "main"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/junit/platform/launcher/TestIdentifier
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.<clinit>(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:86)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.getAgentClass(JUnitStarter.java:244)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:225)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestIdentifier
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

The POM file JUnit snippet:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I also have some JUnit configurations in a IML file:

```
<orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.8.2" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.8.2" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2" level="project" />
```

I have already tried to:

- Delete Maven dependencies on dir .m2 and download them again;
- Clean IntelliJ cache via "File --> Invalidate Caches;
- Update version of dependencies on pom.xml

I read about the possibility of modifying the JUnit Runtime Scope version, but I couldn't managed to do that, since the thread I've found ([java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56387386/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-junit-platform-launcher-testexecutionlistene)), explains how to do it in a Gradle Project. I also have another machine with the same project and same versions of IntelliJ, where the code is working.
May someone help me?
Since now, I thank you so much for all help.

Edit 1: I am trying to run the tests in VS Code and it works. It doesn't work only in IntelliJ.

Comment: Show your pom.xml JUnit dependencies.

Comment: Please provide more information, such as the Pom file, so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: First upgrade IntelliJ to most recent version.. second why using the vintage engine? Also please show the pom.xml file...and test on plain command line first after everything is working import it into IDEA IntelliJ

Comment: Check this out http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html